# Row-wise sum of logical values in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this (with more vars)

```
tb = data.frame(ID=c("a","b","c"),V1=c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),
                V2=c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),V3=c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE) )
tb 

  ID    V1    V2    V3
1  a  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
2  b FALSE FALSE  TRUE
3  c  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

I need to add a fourth variable with the sum of true values by row
like this but conserving all the other vars

```
tb %>%
 select(V1:V3) %>%
 mutate(out = rowSums(.))

     V1    V2    V3 out
1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE   2
2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE   1
3  TRUE  TRUE FALSE   2
```

Comment: Try `tb %>% mutate(res = rowSums(.[-1]))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The dplyr solution**

In a single call, you can use the selection helper `where` inside `across`to feed only the columns that meet a condition (`is.logical`) to `rowSums`.

```
tb %>% mutate(sum = rowSums(across(where(is.logical))))

  ID    V1    V2    V3 sum
1  a  TRUE FALSE  TRUE   2
2  b FALSE FALSE  TRUE   1
3  c  TRUE  TRUE FALSE   2
```

You can also select the columns by name inside across, or with name patterns with `starts_with` or `matches`:

```
tb %>% mutate(sum = rowSums(across(V1:V3)))
#OR
tb %>% mutate(sum = rowSums(across(starts_with("V"))))
#OR
tb %>% mutate(sum = rowSums(across(matches("V\\d"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the `dplyr` way but you *could* use `select()` within `mutate()` like so:

```
tb %>% mutate(out = rowSums(tb %>% select(V1:V3)))


  ID    V1    V2    V3 out
1  a  TRUE FALSE  TRUE   2
2  b FALSE FALSE  TRUE   1
3  c  TRUE  TRUE FALSE   2
```

Comment: Did it consider `TRUE` as 1? Nice I didn't know that.

Comment: @sindri_baldur, i like the pipe in pipe solution ! I wasn't aware of that possibility ! awesome trick